# How do I find the equation of the tangent line to the curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

We have a curve described by the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
    x^2z+2xy=-8\\
   y^2z^2+xy=-4
  \end{cases}$$
We are asked to find a parameterization of the tangent line to the curve at the point $(-2,2,0)$

I've solved similar problems before but I've never seen the curve defined with a system of equations. I need help figuring out how to approach the problem!

My attempt:

$$\text{Let }
  \begin{cases}
   f(x,y,z) = x^2z+2xy+8 = 0 \\
   g(x,y,z) = y^2z^2+xy=-4
  \end{cases}$$
The common normal vector to $\nabla f \;\text{ and }\; \nabla g$ is tangent to the original curve, i.e their cross product.
$$\begin{cases}
   \nabla{f} = (2xz+2y,2x,x^2) \\
   \nabla{g} = (y,2yz^2+x,2zy^2)
  \end{cases}$$
$$\nabla{f}(-2,2,0) = (4,-4,4) \\
  \nabla{g}(-2,2,0) = (2,-2,0)
  $$
$$\nabla{f}\times\nabla{g} = (8,8,0) || (1,1,0)$$
Ultimately, the equation of the tangent is
$$\begin{cases}
   x = -2 +t \\
   y = 2 + t \\
   z = 0
  \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $(u,v,w)$ be a directing vector of the tangent.

Expand

$$\begin{cases}
    (x+\lambda u)^2(z+\lambda w)+2(x+\lambda u)(y+\lambda v)&=&-8\\
   (y+\lambda v)^2(z+\lambda w)^2+(x+\lambda u)(y+\lambda v)&=&-4
  \end{cases}$$
You will obtain 2 polynomials equations in variable $\lambda$.

Annihilate the first order terms in $\lambda$ (of course replacing $(x,y,z)$ by $(-2,2,0)$).

This will give a system of 2 equations in unknowns $u,v,w$ :

$$\begin{cases}
    4u-4v+4w&=&0\\
    2u-2v+0w&=&0
\end{cases}$$

which is enough for determining a direction.

Do you see why ? Intuitively, this annihilation is  the way to express that for an infinitesimal "step" in the direction of vector $(u,v,w)$, one remains on each surface, therefore on their intersection curve.

**Remark:** We assume that the way the surfaces are meeting at the considered point is not "pathological"...

Comment: what do you mean by annihilating the first-order terms?

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm not convinced, could you explain further?

Comment: I mean that for example, the first equation will give rise to $A+B \lambda+C\lambda^2+D \lambda^3=...$, where $A,B,C,D$ are expressions of $x,y,z,u,v,w$ (in fact of $u,v,w$ only). Then the idea is to force $B=0$.

Comment: We are here at the intuitive roots of the infinitesimal calculus (as "grasped" by Leibniz for example). I don't know the degree of rigor asked by your instructor...

Comment: A more rigorous method is to work with tangent planes as described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2605535) on a similar example.

Comment: i.e., obtain the gradient of the first equation (which is the normal to the tangent plane) ; do the same for the second equation ; take the cross product of these two gradients.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful, I’ll upload my attempt!